# Copy-paste multiple hyperlinks with anchor text to Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, copy-paste

I try to copy multiple hyperlinks with the anchor text from a website and paste them to Excel in the same format (anchor text and hyperlink). So, when I click on the hyperlink in Excel, it will take me to the respective website.

It only works for one at a time but not for multiple hyperlinks.

An example can be found on this site: http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2011/982/contents/made?view=plain

Any ideas on how to do this without VBA?

Comment: import webside should do it...

Comment: Could you explain "import website" in more detail please.

Comment: data -> from the web -> insert address -> options -> import with full formating -> ok -> import

Comment: It works for some of the links on the website. Unfortunately not for all of the headlines. Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: to be honest: i never tried :P but it is the big question for now why it doesnt do it... i'll try to run some checks...

Comment: for the links that doesnt work, you better use a source like http://legislation.data.gov.uk/uksi/2011/982/contents/made/data.html (the same links)

Comment: I found a solution that works for all links with no additional manual adjustments or loss of hyperlinks. Mark hyperlinks on website - copy/paste them to OneNote. From there, the hyperlinks can be dragged to Excel in one go.

Comment: true... doing it manually is also possible :P